# Reshaping A Dynamic Array Using Function Parameters

Tags: c++, openacc

Today I found this is in an example file given to me by a company:

```
void mySgemm( int m, int n, int k, float alpha, float beta, float a[m][n],   float b[n][k], float c[m][k], int accelerate )
```

Called with:

```
a_cpu = malloc(..);
b_cpu = malloc(..);
c_cpu = malloc(..);
mySgemm(m, n, k, a, b, a_cpu, b_cpu, c_cpu, true);
```

I can't compile my own similar example, frankly I've never even seen someone take a dynamic array and shape it as such using the function parameters themselves.

Is this a legal call?

---

What boggles my mind is that in the `mySgemm` function they access `a`,`b`,`c` as double arrays, so the array is essentially being reshaped!?

Comment: It is not legal in C++. C++ has no variable-size arrays. It could be legal in C99, depending on how things are declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, it's not valid c++.

i guess the formal argument declarations would pass in c99, as variadic arrays, but i'm not so sure that the actual arguments for those would be accepted

Comment: *actual arguments for those would be accepted* They would not.